# Hola tengo un problema en una aplicacion muy basica pero que no consigo que funcione

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola tengo un problema en una aplicacion muy basica pero no consigo que funcione. La aplicacion tiene dos Activities y cada Activity tiene un boton cuando presionas el boton de la primera activity deberia ir a la segunda Activity pero sin embargo cuando presionas el boton la aplicacion se cierra.

El codigo de la primera Activity es:
   package c.example.intent2;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//Metodo para el boton siguiente
public void Siguiente(View view){
    Intent siguiente = new Intent(this, SegundoActivity.class);
    startActivity(siguiente);
 }
}
```

Este es el codigo de la Segunda Activity:
package c.example.intent2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class SegundoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segundo);
}

//Metodo para el boton atras
public void atras(View view) {
    Intent atras = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(atras);
}
```

}

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar lo agradeceria mucho. Gracias

Comment: que error te muestra?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eso pasa si no declaras alguna Activity en el Manifest. Por ejemplo:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SegundoActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Como verás en el ejemplo estan declaradas las 2 activities en el Manifest

Comment: Muchisimas gracias armen llevaba dias sin saber lo que era y ahora me funciona gracias

Comment: si ese era el problema, aceptala como respuesta. Gracias

Comment: Ahora tengo otra pregunta. Lo siento por ser tan pesado pero tengo tres activities y dos botones cada uno va a una me pasa lo mismo que lo que me pasaba con esta y si pongo lo que tu me has dicho me da error sabrias lo que puede ser

Comment: que te marca el Logcat??

Answer (score -1):

la primera correccion al problema esta en que estas siempre creando nuevas activities y no cerrandolas, esto para el caso de tu main activity.
Si revisas la segunda actividad en el metodo

```
public void atras(View view) {
    Intent atras = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(atras);
}
```

Estas creandola nuevamente, lo que debes hacer en este caso es cerrarla de la siguiente manera

```
public void atras(View view) {
    finish();
}
```

Si este no es el error, te va a servir de todas formas, para podes solucionar el problema entero, es mejor que subas el error que larga en el logcat